# a fast way to calculate orthogonal distance of a point to y=x in R

Tags: r, distance, orthogonal

I have a bunch of points that lie around `y=x` (see the examples below), and I hope to calculate the **orthogonal distance** of each point to this `y=x`. Suppose that a point has coordinates `(a,b)`, then it's easy to see the projected point on the `y=x` has coordinates `((a+b)/2, (a+b)/2)`. I use the following native codes for the calculation, but I think I need **a faster one** without the `for` loops. Thank you very much!

```
set.seed(999)
n=50
typ.ord = seq(-2,3, length=n)   # x-axis
#
good.ord = sort(c(rnorm(n/2, typ.ord[1:n/2]+1,0.1),rnorm(n/2,typ.ord[(n/2+1):n]-0.5,0.1)))
y.min = min(good.ord)
y.max = max(good.ord)
#
plot(typ.ord, good.ord, col="green", ylim=c(y.min, y.max))
abline(0,1, col="blue")
# 
# a = typ.ord
# b = good.ord
cal.orth.dist = function(n, typ.ord, good.ord){
  good.mid.pts = (typ.ord + good.ord)/2
  orth.dist = numeric(n)
  for (i in 1:n){
    num.mat = rbind(rep(good.mid.pts[i],2), c(typ.ord[i], good.ord[i]))
    orth.dist[i] = dist(num.mat)
  }
  return(orth.dist)
}
good.dist = cal.orth.dist(50, typ.ord, good.ord)
sum(good.dist)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As easy as

```
good.dist <- sqrt((good.ord - typ.ord)^2 / 2)
```

It all boils down to compute the distance between a point and a line. In the 2D case of `y = x`, this becomes particularly easy (try it yourself).

Comment: (+1) that should be fast enough! :)

Answer (score 4):

In the more general case (extending to other lines in possibly more than 2-D space), you can use the following. It works by constructing a [projection matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28linear_algebra%29#Orthogonal_projections) `P` from the subspace (here the vector `A`) onto which you want to project the points `x`. Subtracting the projected component from the points leaves the orthogonal component, for which it's easy to calculate the distances.

```
x <- cbind(typ.ord, good.ord)          # Points to be projected
A <- c(1,1)                            # Subspace to project onto
P <- A %*% solve(t(A) %*% A) %*% t(A)  # Projection matrix P_A = A (A^T A)^-1 A^T
dists <- sqrt(rowSums(x - x %*% P)^2)  # Lengths of orthogonal residuals
```

Comment: REALLY nice! But it could maybe be useful to illustrate how it works with another line in the 2D space (different slope and non-zero origin)? Not too sure how to work with (i.e., define) this "subspace to project onto"...

Comment: @ztl Glad you found this useful! For lines passing through the origin, the subspace will be defined by the coordinates of any point on the line (other than the origin itself). So, for example, if the equation of your line is y=2x, you could replace `c(1,1)` in the example above with `c(.5, 1)`. For a line not passing through the origin (i.e. an "affine" subspace), you'd need to apply the algorithm described [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/453072/93561).